# Prevent python lxml from adding plain text a <p> tag

Tags: python, lxml

I don't want lxml add anything to plain text. I left them as they are on purpose. lxml adds plain text a `<p>` tag. Here `value` might be html or plaintext. I need lxml to process html and leave plaintext along.

```
import lxml.html
mixed = ['plaintext', '<a>HTML</a>', '<a>HTML</a>']
for text in mixed:
    html = lxml.html.fromstring(text)
    print(lxml.html.tostring(html))
```

The output:
`b'<p>plaintext</p>'`
`b'<a>HTML</a>'`
`b'<a>HTML</a>'`

What I need is:
`b'plaintext'`
`b'<a>HTML</a>'`
`b'<a>HTML</a>'`

So I come up with several questions.

1. How to know a snippet is pure, without any html tags? (so that I don't have to pass them to lxml), or
2. How to stop lxml from adding a `<p>` tag to plain text?

Comment: Can you add an example of what you have as input and what you want as output?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, I gave a short example now.

Comment: Not sure you can do it with lxml, there are various ways to check if you may have html or not from simply checking for a string starting with an `<` or using  a more complicated regex.

Comment: try html.parser, https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers, use bs4 replace lxml better choice.

Answer (score 0):

try this library... save my but from having to use "re" module when dealing with a XML page where for some dumb reason scrapy selctors working wonky...

```
from w3lib.html import remove_tags

def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    follow = hxs.xpath('//loc').re('.*type=videos.*')
    follow = [remove_tags(x) for x in follow]
    # It wont remove regex lines like \n
```