# Python email - getting the plain text and HTML part of a message

Tags: python, email, imap

I am writing a python email client, and at this point I have the following code:

```
msg = email.message_from_bytes(server.fetch(id, ['BODY[1]'])[int(id)][b'BODY[1]'])
```

`msg` variable has the following value:

```
Message: 
--001a114019b4123b7b0555b61a7c
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"

-- 
*Regards*
*Jack Smith (+374 98 99999)*

--001a114019b4123b7b0555b61a7c
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<div dir=3D"ltr"><br clear=3D"all"><div><br></div>-- <br><div class=3D"gmai=
l_signature" data-smartmail=3D"gmail_signature"><div dir=3D"ltr"><span styl=
e=3D"font-size:small"><b><font face=3D"monospace, monospace">Regards</font>=
</b></span><div style=3D"font-size:small"><b><font face=3D"monospace, monos=
pace">Jack Smith (+374 98 99999)</font></b></div></div></div>
</div>

--001a114019b4123b7b0555b61a7c--
```

The question is, how do I extract the plain text part of the letter which is

```
-- 
    *Regards*
    *Jack Smith (+374 98 99999)*
```

...and how do I extract the HTML part which is:

```
<div dir=3D"ltr"><br clear=3D"all"><div><br></div>-- <br><div class=3D"gmai=
    l_signature" data-smartmail=3D"gmail_signature"><div dir=3D"ltr"><span styl=
    e=3D"font-size:small"><b><font face=3D"monospace, monospace">Regards</font>=
    </b></span><div style=3D"font-size:small"><b><font face=3D"monospace, monos=
    pace">Jack Smith (+374 98 99999)</font></b></div></div></div>
    </div>
```

I have tried the following:

```
for part in msg.walk():
     if part.get_content_type() == 'text/plain':
            return part.get_payload()
```

But for some reason `part.get_payload()` has the same value as the msg itself.
What I am doing wront ?

Comment: You need the whole message, not just a part, to apply message_from_bytes, directly.

Comment: Sorry, can you please provide a minimum code snippet of what you mean

Comment: Get the RFC822 item, rather than just a subsection, and use message_from_bytes on that.

Comment: @Max, the problem is that RFC822 downloads the entire message with attachments. Whereas I want to render only plain-text/HTML part of the letter with only the names of the attachments.

Comment: Then you need to download bodystructure, parse it, store the attachment names; find and get the correct part, which is probably 1.1 but can be anywhere.

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by 1.1?

Comment: BODY[1.1] instead of BODY[1].  The body isn't always in the same place.  You can't hard code it.  If it has attachment it will move.  If it has multiple body types,it will move.  If it has both, it will move.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151423/discussion-between-edgar-navasardyan-and-max).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46053364/3794089 .... Just answered a similar question though you would deffinitly ind it to solve the issue... since its straight up html